# What is the best way to calculate a user's current wallet balance?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions, activerecord-calculations

I am trying to implement a wallet for a web application. The DB design I have come up with for now is a wallet transaction table like below:

```
wallet_tr_id | user_id | amount | tr_type (debit/credit) | datetime | tr_id
```

The users in application can transact via cash or wallet credit. There is another  `transactions` table which hold all transaction info and the ones paid/earned via wallet credits are entered into the above table with the foreign key `tr_id`.

Now what is the best way to display a user his/her current wallet balance?

Should I calculate `sum total of credits - sum total of debits` for that user, or should I maintain `current_balance` for a user in some other table?

PS: There isn't going to be a huge number of transaction for any user eventually.

Comment: I suggest you to maintain current balance field in your database. It is easy when you show the transaction in reports.

Comment: You can show the balance after each and every CR & DR

Comment: Don't store current balance , calculate it. You may want to hold an opening balance against the wallet id and update this to the point where you delete transactions

Comment: @P.Salmon : is it a good practice to delete some transaction?

Comment: @kishor10d sometimes it's a necessity - maybe because of space or performance considerations - and I don't necessarily mean lose them completely , they might need to be kept somewhere (but not necessarily on the production system or even  in an rdbms) in the business depending on business rules and legal/regulatory requirements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for storing the balance. Just calculate it as you said:

```
select sum(case when tr_type = 'credit' then amount else -amount end) as balance
from transactions
where user_id = 12345;
```

Comment: Thanks for the SQL query!

Comment: This is a good answer but isn't it easier to store the current balance in a separate table and retrieve that whenever the user wants to see it. Imagine you want to display the current balance at multiple places and you have to perform this calculation every time on say 10M transaction records.

Comment: @Delali: We try to avoid redundancy in a database, because this can lead to inconsistencies. But yes, you could store he balance in the user table and write a trigger that updates the balance with every new transaction. Thus you could even remove transactions later from the database and still know the current balance. As the OP mentioned that there won't be many transactions per user, however, this is not needed in this particular case; it suffices to get the balance from the transaction table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, well noted.